# Magento2: Mysql Database Slowquery log generating and Magento2 Website going down

Tags: magento2, database

**Below error showing when Website going down**
Any one know solution?
When I restart server then website run again.
But I want to know why server log showing below error.

INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5c8199b30f59f9_84922976` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score` FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `search_index`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `brand_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `brand_filter`.`entity_id` AND (`search_index`.`source_id` = `brand_filter`.`source_id` OR `brand_filter`.`entity_id` = `brand_filter`.`source_id`) AND `brand_filter`.`attribute_id` = 272 AND `brand_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `size_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `size_filter`.`entity_id` AND (`search_index`.`source_id` = `size_filter`.`source_id` OR `size_filter`.`entity_id` = `size_filter`.`source_id`) AND `size_filter`.`attribute_id` = 132 AND `size_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON stock_index.product_id = search_index.entity_id AND `stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `sub_products_stock_index` ON sub_products_stock_index.product_id = search_index.source_id AND `sub_products_stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `sub_products_stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id AND category_ids_index.store_id = '1' WHERE (search_index.store_id = '1') AND (category_ids_index.category_id = 101) AND (brand_filter.value = '1677') AND (size_filter.value  IN ('318', '1175', '9'))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 10000;